# Is there an alternative to fit_generator() without having to set samples_per_epoch?

Tags: keras

I do not understand the design of the `fit_generator()` method. In my example the number of samples may vary and I am not able to determine the number of samples beforehand unless going through the whole data set beforehand.

```py
model.fit_generator(generator=batch_generator(train_data),
                            samples_per_epoch=10000,
                            nb_epoch=1,
                            nb_worker=1)
```

In my scenario I have recorded laps. Since those laps are not finished equally fast, the number of *samples* in each lap may vary.

Imho it would be nice if I could simply throw a `StopIteration` exception to indicate the end of an epoch. Even better would be a `EpochEnd` and a `TrainingEnd` exception to control epochs and the whole training based on these exception but I guess that's not possible.

However, I'd like to know if I can use something like `fit_generator()` without having to know the number of samples of each epoch.

Comment: One epoch is one whole pass over the dataset, so the only way you don't know the samples per epoch is if you don't know the number of samples in your dataset, is that the case?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Yes, more or less. Of course I could iterator over the whole data set at first and count each sample but this is rather slow. Of course I could also do that just once and save the meta information somewhere but I'd rather know a solution that does not rely on the exact number of samples in the data set.